# How to get all the names inside a nested object?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning JavaScript and my teacher asked me to do an exercise that would return an array with all the names of this object:

```
{
  name: 'grandma',
  daughter: {
    name: 'mother',
    daughter: {
      name: 'daughter',
      daughter: {
        name: 'granddaughter'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588073/get-all-children-names-from-object) but the solution does not work for me because my object does not contain any arrays. The code I have so far:

```
    function toArray(obj) {
  const result = [];
    for (const prop in obj) {
        const value = obj[prop];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            result.push(toArray(value));
        }
        else {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function nameMatrioska(target) {

return toArray(target);

}
```

which prints out this : `[ 'grandma', [ 'mother', [ 'daughter', [Array] ] ] ]`

but what my teacher wants is: `['grandma', 'mother', 'daughter', 'granddaughter']`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/b7anka/pen/QrJgRw?editors=1111)

Comment: You're almost there. There are several different was to go about it. You're creating a new array every time. You could instead pass along a shared array into each call so that you're always adding to the same array. You could also do what you're doing, but "empty" the array into the current one after the recursive call.

Comment: You're so close, it would be shameful to just do it for you, especially since this is homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you push an array to an array, where all nested children appears as an array.

To solve this problem, you could iterate the array and push only single items to the result set.

A different method is, to use some built-in techniques, which works with an array, and returns a single array without a nested array.

Some methods:

- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), creates a new array. It works with older Javascript versions as well.

  ```
  result = result.concat(toArray(value));
  ```
- [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with an array and [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for taking an array as parameter list. It works in situ and with older versions of JS.

  ```
  Array.prototype.push.apply(result, toArray(value));
  [].push.apply(result, toArray(value));              // needs extra empty array
  ```
- [Spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for spreading an array as parameters. ES6

  ```
  result.push(...toArray(value));
  ```

  Spread syntax is a powerful replacement for `apply` with a greater use. Please the the [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Examples) as well.

Finally an example with spread syntax.

```js
 function toArray(obj) {
    const result = [];
    for (const prop in obj) {
        const value = obj[prop];
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') { // exclude null
            result.push(...toArray(value));
            //          ^^^                          spread the array
        }
        else {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function nameMatrioska(target) {
    return toArray(target);
}

var object = { name: 'grandma', daughter: { name: 'mother', daughter: { name: 'daughter', daughter: { name: 'granddaughter' } } } };

console.log(nameMatrioska(object));
```

Comment: While I typed you answered! :)

Comment: thanks very much it indeed works I didnt knew about spread syntax but im going to read it now thank you all for the answers. You guys are awesome. I still can't believe it, 3 dots and it solved my problem, wow!!!

Comment: @JoaoMoreira: The problem wasn't the lack of three dots. The problem was thinking you couldn't solve it on your own, which you totally could, if maybe with a little guidance. Just remember that programming is 100% problem solving. At this point, you shouldn't be looking for answers; you should be looking for techniques for discovering solutions.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: well i guess you are right but for what it's worth i learned new things today thanks to everyones answers. i'm really new to programming and i still have a long way to go and i couldnt solve this without a little guidance specially using spread syntax which i didnt even knew about. i knew i was close but at the same time it felt so far away it was frustrating...

Comment: @JoaoMoreira: I hear you. Spread syntax is a convenience syntax, and while nice, is mostly non-essential. The important part is to figure out *what* needs to be done, not merely how to do it. Once you figure out the "what", researching the "how" becomes much easier. Hang in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need `.concat` instead of `.push`. Push adds one item to an array; concat joins two arrays together.

```
['grandmother'].concat(['mother', 'daughter'])
-> ['grandmother', 'mother', 'daughter']
```

Unlike `push`, which modifies the array you call it on, `concat` creates a new array.

```
var a1 = [ 'grandmother' ];
a1.push( 'mother' );
console.log( a1 );
-> ['grandmother', 'mother']

var a2 = [ 'steve' ];
var result = a2.concat(['Jesus', 'Pedro']);
console.log( a1 );
-> ['steve']
console.log( result );
-> ['steve', 'Jesus', 'Pedro']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function toArray(obj) {
  var result = "";
    for (const prop in obj) {
        const value = obj[prop];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            result = result.concat(" " + toArray(value));
        }
        else {
            result = result.concat(value);
        }
    }

    return result; 
}

function nameMatrioska(target) {

return toArray(target).split(" ");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function toArray(obj) {
  var result = [];

  for (var prop in obj) {
    var value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result = result.concat(toArray(value))
    } else {
      result.push(value);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function nameMatrioska(target) {
  return toArray(target);
}

//USER
var names = {
  name: 'grandma',
  daughter: {
    name: 'mother',
    daughter: {
      name: 'daughter',
      daughter: {
        name: 'granddaughter'
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(nameMatrioska(names));
//Output: ["grandma", "mother", "daughter", "granddaughter"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close.
You have to flatten your array in your last step.
Tip: In general be careful when checking for type object because e.g. null, undefined are also objects in JavaScript world!

```js
function isObject(value) {
  if(value === undefined) return "Undefined";
  if(value === null) return "Null";
  const string = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
  return string.slice(8, -1);
}

function collectPropertiesRec(object, propertyName) {
  const result = [ ];
  for(const currentPropertyName in object) {
    const value = object[currentPropertyName];
    if(isObject(value) === 'Object') {
        result.push(collectPropertiesRec(value, propertyName));
    }
    else if(currentPropertyName === propertyName) {
      result.push(value);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function flattenDeep(arr1) {
    return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ?  acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), [ ]);
  }

//USER
const names =  {
  name: 'grandma',
  daughter: {
    name: 'mother',
    daughter: {
      name: 'daughter',
      daughter: {
        name: 'granddaughter'
      }
    }
  }
};

var result = collectPropertiesRec(names, "name");
alert(flattenDeep(result).join(", "));
```